# Jquery get element not working when id contains comma

Tags: jquery

Why does the jquery selector not work when the id contains a comma?
See http://jsfiddle.net/sGQas/188/

```
<div id="1,3">Hello There!</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
  var str = "#1,3";

  if ($(str).length) {
    alert($(str).position().left);
  } else {
    alert('The element "'+str+'" does not exist on the document!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the comma with two backslashes:

```
var str = "#1\\,3";
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dadvn4py/)**

See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/ and https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

Answer (score 0):

Another way to select the element is [attribute-equals-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```js
$(function () {
  var str = '[id="1,3"]';

  if ($(str).length) {
    alert('Text: ' + $(str).text() + ' Left position: ' + $(str).position().left);
  } else {
    alert('The element "'+ str +'" does not exist on the document!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="1,3">Hello There!</div>
```